# Ubuntu - Root user cannot see $JAVA_HOME variable expanded to $PATH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, environment-variables, root

I have created a variable `$JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment'

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk"
PATH="...bla bla bla:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

I also edited `/etc/profile` to have `source /etc/environment` so that all users get Java home. and the directory itself has been made 755 for access.

The printout as `root` for `env`:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8    
SUDO_GID=1000
USERNAME=root
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
USER=root
PWD=/home/ssuser
HOME=/root
SUDO_USER=ssuser
SUDO_UID=1000
MAIL=/var/mail/root
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

But when I do the same as `ssuser` without `sudo`-ing, the environment variable `$JAVA_HOME` is expanded to the actual path.

```
SSH_CONNECTION=193.128.134.115 18497 10.1.4.4 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LANG=C.UTF-8
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
USER=ssuser
PWD=/home/ssuser
HOME=/home/ssuser
SSH_CLIENT=193.128.134.115 18497 22
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
MAIL=/var/mail/ssuser
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=ssuser
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
```

And this has nothing to do with what's set in `/etc/sudoers` for env_var reset/keep settings. Because I have tried this in a different computer and it works just fine.

I am slightly clueless as to why this is happening. Also, something very strange I have noticed is that for a single session sudo users aren't being prompted for password. I have checked `/etc/sudoers` and it is set up correctly to ask password for `root`.

I have tried closing the session and reopening. I can see as them as a normal user, not root. Also, rebooting doesn't do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you don't need to put source `/etc/environment` in `/etc/profile` because it is not a shell script.

It should only contain `key=value` pairs (without `"`). Plus `/etc/environment` doesn't substitute variables like `$JAVA_HOME` here.

`/etc/environment` gets loaded at boot so you need to reboot and it will be available for all users.

This [reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment) has a note specifically saying variable expansion does not work in `/etc/environment`:

> Note: Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.